# Issue with Text area scroll bar?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery mobile 1.4.2 in my application. There is an issue with text area scroll bar, i.e, scrollbar is visible. how can we enable the scroll bar view. I need similar text area with scroll bar as in the following link.

And my code is as follows,

HTML:

```
 <div data-role="page" id="privacy_details">
     <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
         <h3>
             Privacy Policy
         </h3>
     </div>
     
     <div data-role="content">
         <div data-role="fieldcontain">
             <textarea class="txtarea" style="resize: none;">
data
data
data
data
data
data
data
data
data
data
data
data
data
data
             </textarea>
             
             <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="c" target="_blank">OK</a>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .txtarea { height:300px;  max-height: 300px; }
```

My screen shot is as follows,

[image]

Comment: keep the height 100 and check

Comment: I tried with height 100px. It doesn't work

Comment: apply `!important` in your style after height

Comment: `.txtarea { height:300px !important;  max-height: 300px; }` something is overwriting your height

Comment: sorry to say even !important is not working

Comment: have you tried adding overflow? `.txtarea { overflow: scroll; }`

Comment: The same as @TeguhSyahmar has suggested but for vertical scroll only `.txtarea { overflow-y: scroll; }` or `.txtarea { overflow-y: scroll !important; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a fixed `height` for `textarea` and then add `data-autogrow="false"` to prevent it from auto-growing.

- CSS

  ```
  textarea {
    height: 150px; /* any value you want */
  }
  ```
- HTML

  ```
  <textarea data-autogrow="false">

     <!-- text -->

  </textarea>
  ```

> **[Demo](http://jsbin.com/fovut/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

hey your inline styles will be overwrite. you need to add a class or id to your textarea and style it in your css file.

```
.txtarea { 

max-height:100px !important;
height:100px !important; 
overflow:scroll !important;

}
```

and you need to add the `overflow:scroll !important` attribute

Comment: did you add the class txtarea to your textarea?

Comment: on my testsite it works fine, try to remove this in the jquery.mobile-1.4.2.css on line 4189:
textarea.ui-input-text.ui-textinput-autogrow {
    overflow: hidden;
}